# Error building and linking OpenCV when built with LLVM and mingw under windows

Tags: c++, opencv, llvm, mingw-w64

I cannot build OpenCV under windows with llvm(From [www.llvm.org](http://www.llvm.org))
and Mingw(from https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases).
While everything seems to build
correctly, it fails to link and the whole compilation stops as follows:

```
[  9%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/split.avx2.cpp.obj
[  9%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/sum.avx2.cpp.obj
[  9%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/matmul.avx512_skx.cpp.obj
[  9%] Building RC object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj
[  9%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_core460.dll
```

There are tons of messages that indicate that I cannot link to pthread

```
C:\Users\akar\bin\mingw\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a(system.cpp.obj):system.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE[_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE]+0x34): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
C:\Users\akar\bin\mingw\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a(system.cpp.obj):system.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE[_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE]+0xc5): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
C:\Users\akar\bin\mingw\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a(system.cpp.obj):system.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE[_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE]+0x176): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
```

From my bash environment I have defined the following:

```
  export CC="clang.exe -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"
  export CXX="clang++.exe -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"
  export CMAKE_GENERATOR="MinGW Makefiles"
```

if I don't specify the `-target` argument in clang msvc builds correctly. If i try to cheat
the linker by setting

```
alias ld="ld -lpthread"
```

I get this nice error

```
C:/Users/akar/source/repos/opencv/modules/core/include\opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:9: error: no type named 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__gnu_cxx::__recursive_mutex'?
typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        __gnu_cxx::__recursive_mutex
C:\Users\akar\bin\mingw\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\include\c++\ext/concurrence.h:170:9: note: '__gnu_cxx::__recursive_mutex' declared here
  class __recursive_mutex
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Could you share the output of `clang -print-target-triple` ? It is possible that `clang` defaults to the `msvc` runtime instead of `mingw`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The target triple is `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`. Doesn't that change however when I override the target with the `-target` flag?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part of your question. Yes it gets updated with `-target`. Can I ask then how are you invoking `cmake` ? It seems strange to me that you're passing the `-target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` via `CC` with the compiler. Normally it should be passed separately via `CFLAGS`. Could you try to configure your project with: `cmake -S<path_to_source> -B<path_to_build> -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++.exe -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc" -G "MinGW Makefiles"`.

Comment: Also, notice that linking with the `pthread` library is direclty handled by OpenCV's `CMakeLists.txt` https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/CMakeLists.txt#L679

Comment: Building as you suggested I get the following error `C:\Users\akar\source\repos\opencv\3rdparty\libwebp\src\dsp\alpha_processing_sse41.c:52:26: error: always_inline function '_mm_shuffle_epi8' requires target feature 'ssse3', but would be inlined into function
      'ExtractAlpha_SSE41' that is compiled without support for 'ssse3'`. Four times (one for each variable b0, b1, b2, b3) and the compilation stops.

Comment: Could you try passing `-msse3` to the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`? If that doesn't work, maybe try `-march=native` and `-msse3 -msse4.1`. It seems that this is a known issue between OpenCV and Clang (I found several occurrences on Google). I'll try to reproduce on my side to be more helpful.

Comment: @jmmartinez Thank you for your time. I am still getting errors with all those options. Note that the goal is to build using clang with mingw not msvc.